# What were the difference between each Mahabharat and ramayan in different yugas?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana

I have heard many times that Mahabharat and ramayan has been repeated many times in different yugas with same results but with some minor different incidences. What were those different incidences?

Comment: there is no difference. always the same,

Comment: I think you meant different kalpa, not yuga. 4 yugas make one kalpa.